# How to hndle dynamic values coming as string in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using jmeter for testing the performance of a mobile appication which is using IBM Worklight. I am getting 3 dynamic values which comes as a string and i need to handle these values. i trie reular expression extractor but it didnt work. Can any one help me to find out a solution. Dyanamic values are

["{\"jsessionid\":\"0000Mhn7GqWMU1P7Xi9dpJ7mgFb\",\"mbparam\":\"ZjurDsggbg9CZBgd5miAIHMIH%2B5oC7XdSukctItof7AJnpe8UNhlBsgM%2F8w%3D\",\"MP-AUTH-TOKEN\":\"leXozMVUXFYixuYwxgV58EXuRg1Vd0xtpZeouAMQtk6Pd0I1D618motg\"}"]

**Updated**

I tried the regular expression you provided but it's also not working.

[image: Regular Expression]

[image: Sampler]

[image: Response]

[image: Debug Sampler]

These are the steps i have performed. Please guide me if i have done anything wrong.

**Updated**

This is the response i am getting is

{
:   "customerName":"abc",
:   "homeEmail":"",
:   "profileDebitAcc":"01234567",
:   "sessKey":"0000V3EgdxpY937GTWQ3yogRLGq",
:   "mbParam":"hDurAxWHjPT%2BtB7xEyz7Huu51oDOAH8gyNSWIBnHmA9UWuF0lcHGiOy82S0%3D",
:   "responseHeaders":
:   {
:   :   "Content-Language":"en-AU",
:   :   "Date":"Thu, 12 Nov 2015 05:59:50 GMT",
:   :   "Content-Length":"6759",
:   :   "Expires":"0",
:   :   "Content-Type":"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
:   :   "X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0",
:   :   "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
:   :   "Pragma":"no-cache"
:   },
:   "AuthToken":"AHWXZlUt6Rupm1FeBWGu2TEVHZemZwVGbmwmpVxXJR7TMhCA8pWN96ae",
:   "statusCode":200,
:

I need to extract sesskey, mbParam and AuthToken values and send them as list in the next request body.

In the request these values are displayed as

["{\"jsessionid\":\"0000gPQCV4FJ1NQvB8d4Ifd_P9I\",\"mbparam\":\"hDu7DhU%2FjA81TEjwbREmytgqIItmUS4b6rhEojYtcalv0PUs6iaewmtZu6U%3D\",\"MP-AUTH-TOKEN\":\"4fU7Bg20sRRUikHnzmZKcC4ZPyCjVxJnmm7QMnSm6mfT7GlqnySQS2YP\"}"]

[image]

How to handle these values?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `dynamicvalues`
- Regular Expresssion:

  ```
  \["\{\\"jsessionid\\":\\"(.+?)\\",\\"mbparam\\":\\"(.+?)\\",\\"MP-AUTH-TOKEN\\":\\"(.+?)\\"\}"\]
  ```
- Template: `$1$$2$$3$`

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Refer Extracted values as:

- `${dynamicvalues_g1}` - for jsessionid
- `${dynamicvalues_g2}` - for mbparam
- `${dynamicvalues_g3}` - for MP-AUTH-TOKEN

[image: Debug Sampler]

While developing your regular expression remember that you need to escape the following characters with a backslash:

- `[`
- `{`
- `\`
- `}`
- `]`

Other special characters which need escaping are: `.^$*+?()|`

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) page of JMeter's [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html)
- [PCRE Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642)
- [jMeter - Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for the reply. I tried the regular expression you provided but its still showing an error for me. i will provide u the screenshots    /*-secure-
{"errors":["I O: Unexpected character '$' on line 1, column 14"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/. this is the error i am geting.

Comment: If you need to extract the **whole** response, not only 3 dynamic values, use `(?s)(^.*)` as the regular expression and `$1$` as template. See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) for explanation of the regex.

Comment: I tried this one also but its still showing "/*-secure- {"errors":["I O: Unexpected character '$' on line 1, column 14"], "isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/.

Comment: Do we need to use Json Path Extractor to handle these values. If yes could please tell me the syntax for json values